# Convexity of $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{y^2}$

Tags: convex-analysis

I would like to ask the convexity of function

$$f(x,y)=\frac{x}{y^2}$$

where $x\geqslant0, y>0$.

Since $f(x,y)$ is differentiable but not twice differentiable, I used the first order condition and have

$$\frac{x_2(y_1^2-y_2^2)}{y_1^2y_2^2}-\frac{2x_1(y_1-y_2)}{y_1^3}$$

Assume $x_1>>x_2, y_1>y_2$, the expression above is less than 0.

So is it correct that $f(x,y)$ is nonconvex?

Thank you.

Dylan

Comment: You should note that your function **is** twice differentiable on $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y > 0 \}$.

Comment: Thank you for your notice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the characterizations of convexity in the following link, at page 11 ( http://www2.econ.iastate.edu/classes/econ500/hallam/documents/Convex_Opt_000.pdf ) you will see that convexity requires
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y^2} - \left(\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}\right)^2\geq 0.
$$
However, we have 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x^2} = 0,
$$
and 
$$
\left(\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}\right)^2 = \frac{2^2}{(y^3)^2}>0.
$$
Thus, we can never satisfy the first inequality, hence the function cannot be convex.

Comment: Is the requirement a necessary condition or sufficient and necessary condition?

Comment: For twice differentiable functions, it is both necessary and sufficient.

Comment: But the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{y^2}$ is not twice differentiable.